# How to subset a dataframe in R based on the presence of a character at the end of a row

Tags: r, subset

I think this question is so basic that people haven't needed to ask it here before (I promise I have seriously looked), but I'm trying to subset a dataframe in R based on whether the row ends in a period. The original df is a single vector like:

```
df = data.frame('data' = c(186., .08, .23, 182., 81., 16, 19))
```

and I want a dataframe of only the numbers that end in a period, so:

```
df_wperiods = data.frame('data' = c(186., 182., 81.))
```

I found another post that had a good answer for how to do this in python, where it would be something like:

```
df_wperiods = df[~df['name_of_column'].str.endswith(".")]
```

And I expect in R this should be something like:

```
df_wperiods = subset(df, df$data == '%.')
```

But '%' is the wildcard symbol in SQL, not R, and I haven't found the wildcard equivalent in R. So how would I do this in R?

Comment: Is that data supposed to be numeric or strings?

Comment: They're strings!

Comment: Then @akrun's answer is what I would have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataset has `character` strings, then we can match the last character as `.` using `grep` and subset the rows

```
df[grep("\\.$", df$data), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Very sadly when I tried that it resulted in a df with no data :/ -- what is the first $ doing? There's nothing after the periods/we don't want there to be anything after the period, so maybe that's it?

Comment: When I take out that first $, the resulting df pulls in every row with a period at all, which is close but not quite what I'm looking for. Do you know how to get *only* the rows that end in a period?

Comment: @AdrielBarrett-Johnson  The `$` is a metacharacter which means the end of the string.  The `.` is also a metacharacter which means any character.  But as we want to match the `.` as dot character, we escape (`\\`) it to get the literal meaning of that character and not evaluate it as metachracter

Comment: I worry that @AdrielBarrett-Johnson is working with an example data frame that is actually numeric, not character. The example provided in the question will be a numeric column. `186.` will be parsed as a number.

Comment: @akrun That's helpful, thanks! The grep is still picking up all rows that contain a period at all - do you know how to address that?

Comment: @joran, I did a as.character() on my df, and when I do str(df), it says that the variables are as characters, so they should be reading as strings, as far as I understand it

Comment: @AdrielBarrett-Johnson I suspect `as.character` may not have done what you expect. It will have take a numeric value like `186.`, parsed it as numeric and then converted it to the character `"186"`, completely dropping the period. Try akrun's answer on `df = data.frame('data' = c("186.", ".08", ".23", "182.", "81.", "16", "19")))`, and it will work.

Comment: @joran, You're right, trying it with that df did make his answer work. So then should I try to make it read as a string, or how would I do this if it is reading as numeric?

Comment: @abarrettjo Your question is sort of nonsensical if the data is numeric, since there's no sensible way in which a number "ends with a period", unless maybe you select the rows where `data %% 1 == 0` or something like that.